# JQuery Mobile Loader Widget not showing automatically on Ajax Calls

Tags: jquery-mobile

In the JQuery mobile documentation I can read the following:

> The loader widget handles the task of displaying the loading dialog when jQuery Mobile pulls in content via Ajax. It can also be displayed manually for custom loading actions using the $.mobile.loading helper method (See the global method docs).

What does that mean 'pulls in content via Ajax'?

I understand the following; JQuery mobile displays the loading dialog on Ajax calls.
But this isn't working, when I do a simple Ajax get call, the loader doesn't show. (http://jsfiddle.net/QcE8G/).

```
$.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/awesome/number/five", function(data) {
    var json = {
        json: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    $("div").html(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

I can only set the loader widget programmatically like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there some built in logic to show and hide the loader widget or should you always show it programmatically?

Comment: its working http://jsfiddle.net/QcE8G/1/ ajax call is fast, that's it.

Comment: Omar, I know that it's working when you set the loader programmatically. Let me rephrase my question; is it possible to have the loader widget without calling the $.mobile.loading('show'); explicitally?

Comment: no, it works automatically on page change only.

Comment: Ok, I guess I misinterpreted the JQuery-Mobile documentation. Thanks for your response.